# cmucl: run-program output process exited only

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm on debian stretch and install CMUCL from the stable repository. When trying the following

```
(run-program "sh" '("ls") :output T)
```

I get

`#<process 2845 :EXITED>`

without the expected output. Any help please?

Comment: You should consider `sbcl` which is packaged in Debian.

Comment: Yes, sbcl is more active and popular, but you should not discourage people from using other implementations.  It is valuable for the Common Lisp ecosystem to have multiple open source implementations.

Comment: Svante is correct. I'm hip deep in a project for which I can use only cmucl, months after this question was asked and answered, and I'm grateful that this question was asked about cmucl specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Read [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) and [dash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html) & [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). Notice that [POSIX `/bin/sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) is often a symlink to one of them (often `dash`, sometimes `bash`). Be aware of the role of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (e.g. in [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and for [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)). And [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is using `/bin/sh` with `-c`, and your `sh` (assuming it is a POSIX shell) needs `-c` to interpret a string as a command.

You could try

```
  (run-program "/bin/ls" nil :output t)
```

or

```
  (run-program "/bin/sh" '("-c" "ls") :output t)
```

You probably don't have `ls` in your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (but somewhere else in your `PATH`; on POSIX it should be `/bin/ls`) and `/bin/ls` is not a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), but some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable (on Linux; on most Unixes it is some [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and is not a script). So `/bin/sh ls` (or `sh ls`) can't work as you want it to.

To run `ls` there is no need to start a shell! And you might not need to fork a `ls` process for that purpose (of listing files), because you could call [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) as [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) (or find [some](http://www.cliki.net/cl-posix-dirent-susv3-lisp) package doing that).

PS. I have used [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) to test these.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. `ls` was just an example. I would like eventually to perform other task with the shell. Yet I get the output I expect. For instance `(run-program "/bin/sh" '("cat" "'hello' >" "test1.txt") :output t)` should write a file test1.txt as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

In CMUCL

```
(run-program "ls" '("-l") :input t :output t)
```

will work. This works fine, too:

```
(run-program "ls" '("-l" "-h") :input t :output t)
```

and if you need to produce a simple-string, to add it as an argument:

```
(run-program "ls"
  `("-l" ,(format nil "~A" path-name))
  :input t
  :output t)
```

in that case you must use backquote (backtick) and comma.
It is also possible to do:

```
(defun my-ls (file)
  (run-program "ls"
    `("-l" "-h" ,file)
    :input t
    :output t))
```

now you have:

```
(my-ls "/home/user/")
```